# Remove RadContextMenu from Usercontrol WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I have RadPaneGroup, and from the code behind i am adding usercontrol to it.

```
                    <telerik:RadContextMenu.ContextMenu>
                        <telerik:RadContextMenu Name="ctxMenu">
                            <telerik:RadMenuItem Click="MenuItem_Click" Header="Close Current Form" />
                            <telerik:RadMenuItem Click="MenuItem_Click" Header="Close All"/>
                        </telerik:RadContextMenu>
                    </telerik:RadContextMenu.ContextMenu>

                </telerikDocking:RadPaneGroup>
```

The problem is the menu open when i click the user control, which i don't want plz help.

Comment: So what do you want when you click the user control?

Answer (score 0):

Please try by setting the Visibility as Collapsed for Context Menu.